# JSONB not working with Rails 5? JSON field returns as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a jsonb field and for whatever reason, when I call the field, it comes back as a string. Here's the migration:

```
class CreateConferences < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :conferences do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.string :name
      t.jsonb :payload, default: '{}'
      t.jsonb :processed_payload

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If I create a new conference ( `Conference.create(user: user, name: 'test', payload: '{}')` ) and then fetch the payload it comes back as a String. What am I missing here??

Apparently this is now the "expected behavior" in rails now as per [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25594). Not sure how to make this work now...

Guess I need to call JSON.parse() after every request?

Comment: So you're supposed to say `t.jsonb :payload, default: {}` now and you've ended up with a strange default inside the database? What exactly does `\d conferences` say from inside `psql`?

Answer (score 9):

My current solution is to use the following getter method:

```
def payload
    (self[:payload].class == String) ? JSON.parse(self[:payload]) : self[:payload]
end
```

This seems odd that it would be the behavior required to make it work but if you want the prior Rails 4 functionality, you'll need to switch over to this based on [the comments here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25594).

#### Update

I randomly ended up on my question while looking into a completely different issue but figured I'd update this answer.

The answer was to not have the default value be `'{}'` but instead be `{}`. Pretty simple fix :)